# Loading a GPU trained BERTopic model on CPU?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I trained a BERTopic model on a GPU, and now for visualization purposes I want to load it on a CPU.
But when I tried to do that I got:
`RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.`

When I tried to use the suggested fix I got the same problem?
Saw some fix that suggests to save the model without its embeddings model, but don't want to retrain an resave unless its the last option, and would also love if someone could explain what's this embedding model and what's going on under the hood.

```py
topic_model = torch.load(args.model, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

Comment: I'm working off of `bertopic==0.13.0`. As far as I can see in the source code, there's no way to load a model that was saved with an embedding model when you don't have a GPU. I think I'll dig around in their codebase and try to put together a PR.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to save the BERTopic model without the embedding model, you can run the following:

```py
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer


docs = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',  remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))['data']

# Train the model
embedding_model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
topic_model = BERTopic(embedding_model=embedding_model)
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)

# Save the model without the embedding model
topic_model.save("my_model", save_embedding_model=False)
```

This should prevent any issues with GPU/CPU if you are not using any of the cuML sub-models in BERTopic.

> Saw some fix that suggests to save the model without its embeddings model, but don't want to retrain an resave unless its the last option, and would also love if someone could explain what's this embedding model and what's going on under the hood.

The embedding model is typically a pre-trained model that actually is not learning from the input data. There are options to make it learn during training but that requires a custom component in BERTopic. In other words, when you use a pre-trained model, it is no problem removing that pre-trained model when saving the topic model as there would be no need to re-train the model.

In other words, we would first save our topic model in our GPU environment without the embedding model:

```py
topic_model.save("my_model", save_embedding_model=False)
```

Then, we load in our saved BERTopic model in our CPU environment and then pass the pre-trained embedding model:

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

embedding_model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
topic_model = BERTopic.load("my_model", embedding_model=embedding_model )
```

You can learn more about the role of the embedding model [here](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/algorithm/algorithm.html).